# Different ways of accessing attribute values using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
document.getElementById('myId').style;
```

is one way of accessing the style attribute..
Also we can do the same using
 `document.getElementById('myId').getAttribute('style');`

What is the difference between these two ways of getting attribute values..And which one is preferable?

Comment: i think you could also do `document.getElementById('myId')['style']`. afaik, it has similar reason for using `getAttribute()` as @gwynhowell explained.

Comment: that's just another way off accessing an objects properties ..right?

Comment: @JinuJD is called `square bracket notation`, as opposite to the `dot notation`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the first example you're not accessing to the `style` attribute, but to the `style` property. The property's value can be anything, in case of the `style` property is an object. In the second example you're accessing to the style attribute of the tag. The attribute's value can be only string.

In case of some attributes there is a mapping between them. So if you set an attribute `style` on a HTML node, your `style` property is updated and your style is applied. However, this is not always true: a well known bug in some versions of IE (at least till IE7) is that sort of mapping is broken, so set an attribute is not reflected to the property.

So, if you want set an attribute on a HTML node, you have to use the second one. But if you want to access to the property of your object that *represent* a HTML node, you have to use the first one.

In case of the `style`, the first one is strongly recommended.

To make it clear with an example (in modern browsers):

```
document.body.style.border = "1px solid red";
console.log(document.body.style); // [object CSSStyleDeclaration]
console.log(document.body.getAttribute("style")); // "border: 1px solid red;"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer...That's why i get alert(document.getElementById('myId').style) as CSSstyle declaration and  alert(document.getElementById('myId').style) as string   http://jsfiddle.net/rQrRj/  ?

Comment: mhm, not sure I got it, you post in the comment the same code for both; and in the jsfiddle you post there is no style. But the behavior is correct: you set a custom attribute, but because there is no mapping to a property you have that property as undefined. Notice that in old version of IE (at least) if you set an "expando property" you end up to have it as attribute as well, if it's string. The all topic in IE is pretty messed up.

Comment: Is there any other properties which returns object on   document.body.<propertyName>

Comment: A lot, but it depends what you mean with `propertyName`. If you mean some property that are attribute as well, or if you mean in general. You can have a look here : http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-56360201. An example could be the event handlers, where `document.body.onclick` is an anonymous function and `document.body.getAttribute("onclick")` is a string. In some version of IE you have the same broken behavior of `style`: set the attribute from JS don't set the proper event on the object.

Answer (score 4):

`getAttribute` will return the value of non-standard attributes as well as standard ones.

Object property notation will not, since non-standard attributes aren't converted to properties.

```
<a id="test" foo="bar"> ... </a>​

<script>

    console.log(document.getElementById('test').foo); // undefined

    console.log(document.getElementById('test').getAttribute('foo')); // "bar"

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

there is no difference.

```
document.getElementById('myId').style;
```

is a shorthand for

```
document.getElementById('myId').getAttribute('style');
```

the only use for getAttribute('attributeName') would be if attributeName is not a valid javascript variable name, so encapsulating it in quotes would be the only way to access it.

Comment: This is inaccurate. getAttribute will return the value of non-standard attributes as well. This doesn't work with the object property notation, since these non-standard attributes aren't converted to properties. http://jsfiddle.net/rQrRj/

Comment: That's not correct. In fact, if they were the same you should obtain the same result in both get and set a style. However, because the value you obtain is different, they're not the same. See: `document.getElementById("myId").getAttribute("style").border = "1px solid red"` compare to `document.getElementById("myId").style.border = "1px solid red";` In fact the first method returns a string not an object (`CSSStyleDeclaration`).

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is no difference  and detailed example can be found on the following link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style#Example