# style attribute issue with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dom

In the following example, how to get the value of the *style* attribute using DOM api:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<div id="myid" style="foo"></div>
...
```

`document.getElementById('myid').getAttribute('style')` returns "foo" on firefox and google chrome but returns null on IE(9)

Comment: you might want to take a look at jQuery... `$('div#myid').attr('style');`

Comment: are you running this in an onready? i.e. `$(function() { //code here.. });`

Comment: your `<div>` tag isn't properly structured, it should have a full closing tag... `</div>`

Comment: ... true, fixed ! ... but same result :(

Comment: IE is very picky. You adding something to the html will not mean IE will add it to the DOM. If there is actual css is will work(or just make it style='foo:bar'). So, why is there just 'foo' in your style? Don't use the style attribute for custom data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE parses the style sheet and discards syntactically malformed parts. If you test with e.g. `<div id="myid" style="color: #003; foo; line-height: 1.3">` then IE 9 Standards Mode returns `color: rgb(0, 0, 51); line-height: 1.3;`. So it has converted the color notation, and it has discarded the malformed part. In your case, the CSS code becomes empty after removing the bad part.

Older versions of IE behave differently, and so does IE 9 in Quirks Mode. As a rule, avoid reading the `style` HTML attribute, and read the `style` DOM property instead. Regarding the difference, see question [Different ways of accessing attribute values using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258259/different-ways-of-accessing-attribute-values-using-javascript).

Comment: You could use the `outerHTML` property (supported by all currently used versions of IE, though there are problems with other browsers) and then parse the markup to get the `style` attribute value. Rather clumsy. And I don’t see why you would need this. The `style` attribute as such is not that relevant; it's the combined styles that matter. And what would you do with those parts of a stylesheet that are syntactically malformed and ignored by browsers?

Comment: outerHTML miss the style attribute

Comment: You’re right in the sense that IE shows the *parsed* value here, too, so the malformed `foo` gets stripped off. What is your purpose of using a `style` attribute with a value that is not syntactically a style sheet?

Comment: client-side templating. eg.   <div id="myid" style="$foo"></div>

Comment: @Soubok, either store things like `$foo` in variables (after all, in client-side programming you can use normal programming, too), or put then into `data-*` attributes, e.g. `data-style="$foo"` and generate `style` attribute values (if needed) only when you can resolve things like `$foo` to real CSS code.